# CCRepeatForever doesn't exists in cocos2d-iphone 3.0?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Im trying to create sprite animation in cocos2d 3.0.
In all tutorials that i read there is a class named CCRepeatForever. But in cocos 3.0 it doesn't exists anymore. How can i replace it?

This is my code:

```
self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];
```

PS Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

The class is now named `CCActionRepeatForever`.

Replace it with:

```
[CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim]];
```

Comment: I didn't find any examples with this class. Can you show me one?

Comment: it's the same class just named differently

Comment: Seems CCAnimate has been renamed too =) Ive got this `Unknown receiver 'CCAnimate'; did you mean 'CCAnimation'?`

Comment: I replaced and I've got this https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nefa3bhkv501ls/Screenshot%202014-02-05%2000.17.39.png